# Can't use requestAction from Shell in Cakephp 2.5

Tags: php, shell, cakephp, dispatch

As stated, when I use in a shell :

```
$this->requestAction('/sites/zaz/option1');
```

The action doesn't get triggered. To test this, I tried :

```
public function zaz($option1 = null) {
        CakeLog::write('acces', 'action triggered');
        return 'got it !';
    }
```

And the action isn't done and there is no log written whatsoever. All my other logs do work.

So I tried :

```
$this->requestAction('/sites/actionwhichdoesntexist/option1');
```

And I got an error stating that the action doesn't exist.

I really need to use requestAction, because I have a model/controller and this action is typically testing that a ressource is still alive. I want to use requestAction in order to smoothly handle the "requested" aspect, so that I will build something more robust :

```
if(empty($this->request->params['requested']))
            $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'proxies', 'action'=>'index', 'admin'=>true));
        else
            return true;
```

I tried with 2.4.1 and 2.5, nothing just happens, no output is given, even if I put a 'die()' in the action.

Comment: 2 things 1) probably you're accessing a _different_ action, or the beforeFilter or a component is interfering - it depends on the defined routes and beforeFilter/component logic 2) **Don't use requestAction at all** for what you describe - put the logic in a model method and _call the model method_.

Comment: Thanks, it was indeed beforeFilter which was missing (need to be logged). But there is no data/sql related stuff in the action I want to perform, that's why I initially didn't want to put it in a model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the first comment, I should have checked the beforeFilter function.