# requestAction is not working in CakePHP 2 Shell Command

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm attempting to make a cron shell, and the ability to use requestAction for this is crucial.

For testing purposes, I've reduced my Shell down to just this:

```
class CronShell extends AppShell {
    public $uses = array('Cron');
    
    public function main() {
        $this->requestAction(['controller' => 'events', 'action' => 'play', 38, 0, true, true]);
        echo "This will never be printed to the console, it dies before this.";
    }
}
```

And I still cannot get this to run. It simply returns apparently successful, but actually is not. (no error) [Another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24112370/cant-use-requestaction-from-shell-in-cakephp-2-5) suggested beforeFilter (and other lifecycle methods) could be the cause, but <s>I've ensured that is not the case</s>. **See update.**

1. Other controller/actions aren't working.
2. Removing the action's `return` doesn't help.
3. Using a string-based call doesn't help.
4. CakePHP v2.10.22

**Update:** It looks like the Auth component may be causing a redirect to `users/login` in `AppController`. Yet I see nowhere that I tell it to redirect here, and I don't even *have* a `users/login` action. When I remove `'Auth'` from my `public $components = []`, the shell runs on CLI.

But I'm having trouble disabling Auth! I've tried allow(*), setting the redirects to false, even trying `$this->components = ['']`. I am always redirected to users/login.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out it wasn't the *beforeFilter* or any part of the lifecycle, but I did have the `Auth` component on my AppController like such:

```
public $components = [
    'Session',
    'Auth' => [
        'loginRedirect' => ['controller' => 'worlds', 'action' => 'route']
    ]
];
```

Which, no matter what I did to allow or simulate Auth for cli, just constantly redirected me. So I reduced the above to just Session and wrote under,

`if (php_sapi_name() !== 'cli')`

This:

```
$this->components = [
    'Session',
    'Auth' => [
        'loginRedirect' => ['controller' => 'worlds', 'action' => 'route']
    ]
];
```

And that removed Auth from the equation. I would have expected CakePHP 2's console to give me any indication it was being redirected, but I'll bet future versions handle it better.

Comment: Future versions dropped `requestAction()`, which is indeed better, as all it ever did was encouraging bad application architectures ;) If you need to share functionality between controllers and shells, then this indicates that your code should be put in a service.

Comment: No worries @ndm, you'd be proud of my refactored events controller. Fat models and such. The trouble here (and why I'm on Cake 2) is that the whole system started in early 2013 and at this point, what's done is done and I must focus on making the new; the software was never intended to do what I'm asking of it, but it's really taking it like a champ.